# php power of number mod number not work

Tags: php, math

why this function return 0 ?

```
public function encrypt(){
    return (pow(123,17)%3233);
}
```

Comment: `123^17` is way bigger than `PHP_INT_MAX`

Comment: What is your function trying to do?

Comment: @Omaralquraishi Use BC math lib, e.g. `echo bcmod(bcpow(123, 17), 3233);`

Comment: There's also a [bcpowmod](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.bcpowmod.php) function which is probably a bit faster. Btw:Your private exponent is 2753. haha, got your private key ;-)

Comment: @Rizier123 You should probably post an answer

Comment: @hek2mgl You want me to write an answer 2'o clock in the morning without coffee :]?

Comment: @Rizier123 I'm in California atm. It's 17:50. :) Gute Nacht!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is you get an integer overflow. Your number is way bigger than `PHP_INT_MAX`. So to still be able to do this calculation you can use the [BC math library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) .

So just use [`bcpowmod()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.bcpowmod.php), e.g.

```
echo bcpowmod(123, 17, 3233);
```

Comment: thanks it's very fast than bcmod(bcpow(123, 17), 3233);